# How do I override this onPaint method to pass a list?

Tags: c#, vb.net, overriding, onpaint

I have overridden the onPaint method and I am planning to do a small modification for which I need to pass a list to this C# script from my VB.NET code, Below is my code.

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
            {
                base.OnPaint(e);    
                e.Graphics.Clear(SystemColors.Window);
                for (int i = 0; i < Months.Length; i++)
                {

                    foreach (MonthViewDay day in Months[i].Days)
                    {
                        if (!day.Visible) continue;

                        MonthViewBoxEventArgs evtDay = new MonthViewBoxEventArgs(e.Graphics, day.Bounds, day.Date.Day.ToString(),
                            StringAlignment.Far,
                            day.Grayed ? DayGrayedText : (day.Selected ? DaySelectedTextColor : ForeColor),
                            day.Selected ? DaySelectedBackgroundColor : DayBackgroundColor);

                        if (day.Date.Equals(DateTime.Now.Date))
                        {
                            evtDay.BorderColor = TodayBorderColor;
                        }
//this is where I plant to add my code IF I get to know to pass a list
                         else
                        {
                          //search if day.Date is present in the list
                          //if present then update a different border color 
                        }                     
                        DrawBox(evtDay);
                    }
```

Just a note, my list parameter is another custom class. 
Any solutions or approach I should use here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass the list via the onPaint event what you can do is pass it another way and use that parmater in the on paint event

You can modify you class as follows :

```
Object obj = new Object();
List<int> _list = new List<int>();
Public void PassList(List<int> myList)
{
     lock(obj)
     {
         _list = myList;
     }
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
     lock(obj)
     {
           // Do something with the _list
     }
}
```

Comment: where exactly should I be calling this PassList method from my VB.NET code? Is it during the form load event?

Comment: This depends on your business logic , you can pass in on form load  or in the form constructor

Comment: Sorry, am new to this and am still wondering when this onPaint would be called. Am not sure whether it would be called when my form constructor is invoked or onFormLoad.. :(  Any help ?

Comment: onPaint  is called by the .Net infrastructure when need or by forcing the forms invalidation

Comment: I was able to add a Handler in VB.Net for the onPaint even during which I am passing the list of objects.. Thanks a ton..

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `onPaint` event is

```
protected virtual void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
```

Therefore you can't pass any other arguments, especially that `PaintEventArgs` doesn't have any additional property such as `Data` or `ExtendedProperties`

- You can declare your list on form level [or, should I say, class level] and use it within your `onPaint`.
- If, lets say, your paint is happening on different thread, when you set the thread, you can pass your list using `Thread.SetData` and then retrieve it in your `onPaint` by issue `Thread.GetData`.
- you can set your list in some sort of static class and grab it from there

Comment: I didn't want to try the thread approach for some reason... +1 for the class level advice :)

Comment: @VenkatRaman I don't push it on you. Just saying that "if" another thread is involved.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did ...

I added a handler for the paint event

```
  AddHandler this.monthView1.Paint, AddressOf this.iPass //this is the method that would pass the list
```

I updated my custom control by adding a method as mentioned by @User

```
public void PassList(List<DateTime> myList)
    {
        lock (obj)
        {
            _list = myList;
        }
    }
```

Now, Inside my      `protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)` event I was able to access the _list and perform appropriate operations